# How to assign a contributor role of subcription to a serviceprincipal using api or how to use subscription object

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, microsoft-graph-api, azure-api-management

I try assign a contributor role of subcription  to a serviceprincipal using api.
Here is the information:
subcription ID:b59c6b1b-xxxxxxxxxx
serviceprincipal ID：73eb9e1e-xxxxxxxx
contributor ID: b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c(Azure built-in contributor role ID，I get it use 'az role definition list --query "[].{name:name, roleType:roleType, roleName:roleName}" --output tsv' by az cli.Is it right?)

I use the api like this

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/b59c6b1b-xxxxxxxxxx/appRoleAssignedTo
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 110

{
  "principalId": "73eb9e1e-xxxxxxxx",
  "resourceId": "b59c6b1b-xxxxxxxxxx",
  "appRoleId": "b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c"
}
```

But I got the error respone like this

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_ResourceNotFound",
        "innerError": {
            "client-request-id": "4fed54c4-xxxxxxxxx",
            "date": "2021-01-11T12:00:08",
            "request-id": "4fed54c4-xxxxxxxxx"
        },
        "message": "Resource \u0027b59c6b1b-xxxxxxxxxxx\u0027 does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."
    }
}
```

It means that subcription didn't find by ID, in this example, I use subcription ID, I think may be I should use subcription ObjectID like other example resouce .But I don't find the method to get subcription ObjectID by using portal or api. Or maybe I  fix error info into resourceID.So I want to know what infomation is I need to know to assign a contributor role of subcription to a serviceprincipal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the wrong API, this [MS Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) is to assign [AAD App role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps) to the service principal, what you need is to assign the [RBAC role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles) to the service principal in the subscription, you need to use this API - [`Role Assignments - Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roleassignments/create),  you could click the `Try it` button in this page, login your account and try it directly.

Make sure the client/user you used to get the token has the permission `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write` to create the role assignment, e.g. `User Access Administrator` or `Owner`.

**Sample:**

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/{scope}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/{roleAssignmentId}?api-version=2015-07-01

{
  "properties": {
    "roleDefinitionId": "/subscriptions/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/de139f84-1756-47ae-9be6-808fbbe84772",
    "principalId": "xxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

For more details, follow every steps in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-rest).

Besides, if you can accept to use Azure CLI, you could use this command [`az role assignment create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/role/assignment?view=azure-cli-latest#az_role_assignment_create).

Comment: Thanks for your answer,the API from Azure is useful，but i want to use the api from Graph so that I don't need to get the different auth token twice,because the most of my app use the api of Graph. Is there API of Graph can assign RBAC role?

Comment: @lhb6540 No, it can't. MS Graph does not take charge of the subscription level things, for the subscription operations, you need to use azure rest api - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/

Answer (score 0):

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{id}/appRoleAssignedTo
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 110

{
  "principalId": "principalId-value",
  "resourceId": "resourceId-value",
  "appRoleId": "appRoleId-value"
}
```

Here the {id} and "resourceId" is the object id of the Service Principal.

You can get this in one of the two ways described below :

**Option 1 :**

**From Portal :**

Azure Active Directory >> App Registrations >> Select All Apps from the dropdown menu >> find your app and click on it.

[image]

**Option 2 :**

**From Graph**

Using `GET /servicePrincipals`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/serviceprincipals?$filter=startswith(displayName, 'Application-Name')
```

You will have to replace the Application name above.
The output of the above request will have the guid value under the **id** key.